# Is Bluetooth Programming with Windows Sockets compatible only with Microsfoft bluetooth stack?

Tags: sockets, winapi, bluetooth

While implementing a communication test between Bluetooth enabled PC and an android tablet with the [BluetoothChat](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/main/BluetoothChat) app the easiest way to successfully implement was the winsock2 approach as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-programming-with-windows-sockets). The dongle was a TPLink-made on Windows 7 (TPLin UB400) with a default system-provided drivers.

The same test also performed ok on a Windows 10 notebook with an internal Bluetooth hardware with a default set of drivers.

But the problem aroused when I tried to run the same test on

- A Toshiba notebook with Windows 7 and Toshiba Bluetooth Stack
- the same TPLink dongle with a recommended drivers for Windows 7 (CSR Harmony). Probably the information that Windows 7 default drivers are compatible with it was missed by the manufacturer so it still lists XP and 7 as requiring these drivers

With both tests the attempt to create a socket

```
socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM)
```

ended with WSAEAFNOSUPPORT error

Looking at the drivers installed in all three case, the following emerged for winsock2 approach to be working :

- The Microsoft Bluetooth stack should be installed (Generic Bluetooth Radio, Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator)
- There should be present a network adapter driver Bluetooth RFCOMM TDI

But not in the ms-provided docs and elsewhere could I find the explicit mentioning that if the user has any third-party Bluetooth stack installed (instead of ms-provided), no sockets functionality would work.

Can someone confirm that this was and is the fact for some unknown reason never articulated?

Comment: A long time ago there were 4 Bluetooth drivers for Windows: BlueSoleil, Toshiba, WidComm and, starting from Win XP SP2, native MS. These days there are only 2 popular: MS and Toshiba. Each Bluetooth driver has it own API. WinSock API can be used with MS drivers only on any Windows platforms. BLE API is also different for each Bluetooth driver. There are at least 2 (was more) Bluetooth library that supports few Bluetooth drivers: 32feet and Bluetooth Framework. Both support MS and BS, but Bluetooth Framework also supports Toshiba.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko, nice outline. thank you. Is there a minimum "code denominator" (and probably requirement from MS to the manufacturers) that allows implementing RFCOMM communication using any bluetooth stack?

Comment: No, as I described above each Bluetooth driver has its own ansolutely different API/SDK. Microsoft provides it as WinSock API (and as few separate functions). Toshiba and BlueSoleil as set of standard DLLs with exported functions. WidComm SDK was designed as C++ lib with classes. So to be able to use it in universtal way you can use third-party libs (Bluetooth Framework (VCL, C++, .NET) or 32feet (.NET) or may be other). As far as I know there is no one lib that supports Harmony stack, but fortunately it is not popular.

Comment: Also there is at least one non-standard Bluetooth device: BLED112. It appears as COM port in system and allows to use BLE features on any Windows platform (starting from Win 95). It has own API as well and as far as I know only Bluetooth Framework supports it and provides universal interface for it. Also there are few Python libs but they simple translates the BLED112 API to Python calls.